# Alternative to XML-style objects in Spring configurations?

Tags: java, spring

Spring's IoC framework is pretty nifty. Writing configuration objects in XML is not.

Are there any alternatives to loading complex objects and injecting them into your beans in Spring? Property files are too simple (they contain only key-value pairs). I'm interested in building lists, maps, etc. I was thinking something along the lines of a JSON object.

Comment: perhaps you want to read this first http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/CreateListMapInContext.htm and http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/BeanInjectionCollectionMap.htm also this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html read about util:list util:map util:set

Comment: Thanks. util: is probably the way I'll go if there isn't anything better :)

Comment: Yes indeed just separate the beans by files if they're huge and include them as usual :)

Comment: It seems that using something like a <util:map> results in a Map<String,String>. How would I go about building a map that contains complex objects?

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?79497-define-complex-object-in-Map-using-util-schema and this perhaps http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/x-springXOM/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: I actually came upon that same forum post. Thanks :) I guess the part that is annoying is that I can't put arbitrary data in the map (combinations of strings and integers). If i stick to only using primitive types, I should be able to cast them in my code (which is perhaps a little ugly). I'm actually considering storing the config in JSON and using something like gson to map it to a java object.

Comment: Actually, ignore my previous comment. Deserializing from json is just as much a problem due to java's type safety. Maybe apache commons configuration is not a bad idea after all.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 3.0, and further enhanced in 3.1, Spring now has complete support for Java-based configuration.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: I looked at Spring's Java-based configuration already. It's nice for dynamically defining your injections, but really it's not a great format to store general configuration in (mostly because Java's syntax for static collections isn't so great).